# Timeout exception keeps triggering ASP.NET Core 3.1 Angular 9

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm facing a frustrating error in ASP.NET Core Angular project. A weird timeout error keeps triggering most of the time application trying to execute.

Few solutions I tried was

spa.Options.StartupTimeout = new System.TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);

at angular.json

```
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "CRapp:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "CRapp:build:production",
          "progress": true
        }
      }
```

Here prgresss:true specified

Also this is my scripts in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "echo starting && ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run CRapp:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
```

Here an echo is given

But still I am getting that error and hate the ASP.NET core environment now.
Please help me.

This is the error triggering. Sometimes when hitting f5 will loads the page. But now its not at all working.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   TimeoutException: The Angular CLI process did not start listening for
>   requests within the timeout period of 0 seconds. Check the log output
>   for error information.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Util.TaskTimeoutExtensions.WithTimeout(Task
>   task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, string message)

Comment: Does this happen locally when you run the project?

Comment: yes.. locally it happens wheever application starts to run. The weird part is if I run using ng server on that clientapp folder , angular app running without any issue

Comment: The weird thing is that if I create an ASP.NET Core 3.1 + Angular project in VS 2019 and add the timeout you have, it all works :\

Comment: The fact that it says "timeout period of 0 seconds" is pretty odd. Are you setting the timeout before calling UseAngularCliServer?

Comment: No bro, I'm setting it before that. But sometimes it shows 30 seconds and thus I set the timeout to 5 mins.. terrific

Answer (score 0):

Facing same issue and im doing following steps

1. Delete all the folder inside node_modules which is sitting under from my project
2. run "npm install" from the my projcet location

And its works but its not permanent fix.